# Can spring boot be configured to have a fall back when vault is down?

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-vault-config, spring-vault

I'll be deploying my application to aws but the vault instance is not configured there yet so I was wondering if there is a way to use a properties files instead if vault is not up. The app doesn't start successfully when Vault is not started.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something useful can be done with this property:

spring.cloud.vault.enabled